# Pine Code for Tradingview rsi Y axis question

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

Is there a way to split the Y axis on rsi using pine code on Tradingview? Basically, I want to display positive volume ta.rsi on the 50-100 part of the Y axis and display negative volume ta.rsi on the 50-0 part of the Y axis.

The visual display of how I want it to look works exactly how I wanted it to using volume ta.sma, but then it leaves me having to adjust every time frame for every ticker, because it's not a scale of 0-100 like rsi is. But then when I use volume ta.rsi, it doesn't display negative volume down and positive volume up, like the volume ta.sma does.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Rescaling/Normalizing](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/faq/Techniques.html#how-can-i-rescale-an-indicator-from-one-scale-to-another) the value of your indicator from another scale